# clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, android-studio, gradle, cmake, static-libraries

Accessing static library libadd.a from CPP file.

CPP file is compiled using CMakeList.txt which compile and application generate libnative-lib.so file.

**Updated CMakeList.txt**

```
**target_link_libraries(
                       native-lib
                       ${log-lib}
                       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libadd.a)**
```

**Accessing function add() in native-lib.cpp file**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "../../../staticLib/files/add.hpp"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_oncall_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello SUCESSS its 12";

    std::string hello1 = "Hello FAILED it is not 12";

    addition::my::work::abc     Obj;
    Obj.add(5,7);

    if(Obj.add(5,7) == 12)
    {
     return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello1.c_str());
    }

}
```

**Error when trying to build the code.**

Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/oncall/Desktop/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/oncall/Bha/MyApplication3/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64 --target native-lib}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnative-lib.so
FAILED: : && /home/oncall/Desktop/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=x86_64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/oncall/Desktop/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/oncall/Desktop/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  /home/oncall/Desktop/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/21/liblog.so ../../../../libadd.a -latomic -lm && :
/home/oncall/Desktop/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: ../../../../libadd.a(add.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against '_ZN8addition2my4work3abc5countE' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
/home/oncall/Desktop/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: shared library text segment is not shareable
**../../../../libadd.a(add.o):add.cpp:function addition::my::work::abc::getCount(): error: undefined reference to 'addition::my::work::abc::count'
../../../../libadd.a(add.o):add.cpp:function addition::my::work::abc::~abc(): error: undefined reference to 'addition::my::work::abc::count'
../../../../libadd.a(add.o):add.cpp:function addition::my::work::abc::~abc(): error: undefined reference to 'addition::my::work::abc::count'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see** invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

**add.cpp of libadd.a**

```
#include "add.hpp"

namespace addition{
namespace my{
namespace work{

int abc::add(int x, int y) {

    return (x+y);
}


int abc::getCount(){
    return count;
}

abc::~abc(){
    count--;
}
};
};
};
```

Comment: Looks like `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libadd.a` refers to a **non-existent** file. You may print this path via `message("PATH: ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libadd.a")` and check whether given files actually exists.

Comment: The edited post still doesn't answer to the question about location of `libadd.a` library.